# Multiple Input Keras Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to train a Keras Model where the input is a vector of size `(20, 300)`. 
But the problem is that I need also to feed the model with a fixed list of vectors that should be used on each training step.

the list of vectors is fixed for all training examples.. so Here's what I've tried.

```
def create_model(num_filters=64, embedding_dim=300, seq_len=20):
  # input1 Shape (?,20,300)
  input1 = Input(shape=(seq_len,embedding_dim,), dtype='float32') # Input1 taken from the model input
  # input2 Shape (5,20,300)
  input2=get_input2() # Input2: taken from outside the model


  # CNN Encoding of Input 1 
  convs = []
  filter_sizes = [1,2,3]
  for fsz in filter_sizes:
    x = Conv1D(num_filters, fsz, activation='relu',padding='same')(input1)
    x = MaxPooling1D()(x)
    convs.append(x)    
  output1 = Concatenate(axis=-1)(convs)
  output1 = Flatten()(output1)


  # CNN Encoding of Input 2 
  convs1 = []
  filter_sizes = [1,2,3]
  for fsz in filter_sizes:
    x1 = Conv1D(num_filters, fsz, activation='relu',padding='same')(input2)
    x1 = MaxPooling1D()(x1)
    convs1.append(x1)    
  output2 = Concatenate(axis=-1)(convs1)
  output2 = Flatten()(output2)
```

However this implementation throws a value error.

> "ValueError: Layer conv1d_60 was called with an input that isn't a
>   symbolic tensor. Received type: ."

How this can be done in Keras?

Comment: what is input2? Seems to be the source of the error.

Comment: yes, here's the problem.
input2 is a fixed list of vectors that should be fed for each training batch or example.
I couldn't find a better way of doing this other than calling a function that return this list each time.

Comment: Why don't you pass them with an Input layer?

Comment: Thank you for replying @MatiasValdenegro
In order to pass them with input layer, the two inputs should be at the same shape, at least in shape[0]. but this is not my case.
Here: input1 of shape (?, 20, 300) and input2 of shape (5, 20,300).
In other word, for each training step: there should be a different input1 (different batch of training examples) and the same input2 for all training steps.

Comment: In that case you still need to provide them with an Input layer, and manually make batches of the extra data so the samples dimension matches. I do not think there is any other way.